# Problem with BAUD rate in hm-10 bluetooth module

Tags: module, arduino, bluetooth, hm-10

I bought an hm-10 bluetooth ble module , and connected it to my arduino nano , when the hm-10 module was set to 9600 baud rate it worked just fine,

The problem is that i've changed the baud rate of the hm-10 module to 38400 with the arduino ide console and now i cant get it back to 9600, because the module doesn't understand the commands from the console (eg. if i write AT+BAUD4 the console just return weird characters)

I tried changing the software serial.begin to 9600 or 38400 but nothing works, my code is

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial miBT(10, 11);

void setup(){

Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Listo");
miBT.begin(9600);

}

void loop(){
if (miBT.available())
Serial.write(miBT.read());

if (Serial.available())
miBT.write(Serial.read());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the baud rate in Arduino serial monitor?

[image: Arduino serial monitor]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the issue I had was exactly the same as yours, but when I set the baud rate on my module to 1200 (AT+BAUD7) then reset it, my module would only respond with "OK" when trying to set the baud rate again. After searching on the net I found this

https://people.ece.cornell.edu/land/courses/ece4760/PIC32/uart/HM10/DSD%20TECH%20HM-10%20datasheet.pdf

On page 17, it states that:

> Note: If setup to Value 7, After next power on, module will not support any AT
> Commands, until PIO0 is pressed, Module will change Baud to 9600.

Hope this helps